# Relation between Power Spectral Density and RMS of the signal

Tags: frequency-spectrum

I have a pressure signal at two locations `(r=1 and r=1.3)`. I found the power spectral density (PSD) and the root mean-square (RMS) of the signal. My question is why at `r=1` the PSD is higher than the PSD at `r=1.3` while the RMS at `r=1` is less than RMS at `r=1.3.`

I mean is there any relation between PSD and RMS of the signal?

[image]

Comment: the premise to your question is not completely correct. *" at `r=1` the PSD is higher than the PSD at `r=1.3`* [at some frequencies] *while the RMS at `r=1` is less than RMS at `r=1.3.`"*

Comment: Thank you. That is correct. Just to be clear, the second plot represents the Root Mean Square of the pressure signal Pressure_rms. You mean the RMS at r=1 is less than at r=1.3 because the PSD at r=1 is higher that PSD atr=1.3 at some points. Is that correct?

Comment: yes.  at more frequencies the PSD at `r=1.3` is higher that the PSD is at `r=1'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instantaneous power is:

$$ p_x(t) = |x(t)|^2 $$

mean power is:

$$\begin{align}
 P_x &= \lim_{T \to \infty} \quad \frac{1}{T} \int\limits_{-\frac{T}{2}}^{+\frac{T}{2}} p_x(t) \, dt \\
\\
&= \lim_{T \to \infty} \quad \frac{1}{T} \int\limits_{-\frac{T}{2}}^{+\frac{T}{2}} |x(t)|^2 \, dt \\
\end{align}$$

the relation between Power Spectral Density to mean power is:

$$ P_x = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} S_x(f) \, df  $$

the relation between Root Mean Square to mean power is:

$$ P_x = \lVert x(t) \rVert^2 $$

Comment: No, $|x(t)|^2$ is instantaneous energy? $d/dt |x(t)|^2$ is power

Comment: Sorry @OverLordGoldDragon , you missed the mark again.  Just curious, are you an Electrical Engineer?

Comment: Graduated as one, never considered myself one. I do know a thing about circuits that'll blow your mind though. At any rate, [what'd I miss](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/333721/98160)?

Comment: So, you have a real-valued signal represented as a voltage, $v(t)$, and you apply that voltage to a resistor $R$.  What is this quantity:  $$ \frac{v^2(t)}{R} = v(t) \times \frac{v(t)}{R} = v(t) \times i(t) $$ ?

Comment: While I'm sorting this out, what would be the instantaneous energy?

Comment: hol'up, $\sum |x|^2$ is _integrating_ in continuous-time... I might be a stupid. So then do we have a discrete definition of instantaneous energy, besides like $(\int |x|^2)[n]$ (that math's probably off but you get it)? also that example's good food for thought but not justification, e.g. $\text{signal} = v \cdot i$

Comment: I spent several hours to conclude it's indeed power. It bugged me that the implication is that energy is necessarily an aggregate quantity, yet we can obviously measure e.g. instantaneous kinetic energy. Wrestling with calculus and foundations of waves from restoring force, one finds that the energy of a _differential_ element is indeed given by $|x(t)|^2$, but any finite realization requires aggregation, hence "instantaneous energy" is zero. And, $E(t)$, as derived from $\int P(t) dt$, is implicitly aggregating from some reference.

Comment: and that, a signal in abstract and general definition obeys the same logic per standard continuum, which subsumes uniformity and ordinality, plus, built on Fourier which is sines, put that all together and fix my lazy English... it's power. -- now, to tackle the discrete case, if we insist on sample-by-sample, one could argue each sample is indeed energy, in that we aggregate over the sampling period with uniformity assumption.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon, you might wanna check out [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16821/how-to-check-if-a-signal-is-power-signal-or-energy-signal/16822#16822) and related stuff.  Note that, in the power spectrum, we calculate the aggregate of power over all frequencies and it's still power.  That's because power spectrum would be *"volts-squared-per-hertz"*.