Intuitive understanding of the relationship between the variance of a Wiener process and the variance of white noise
The Wiener process $W(t)$ is said to be the integral of white noise $\xi(t)$ from $0$ to $t$. That is,
$$W(t) = \int_{0}^{t} \xi(t')dt'$$
However, the variance of $\xi(t)$ is infinite, but the variance of $W(t)$ is not infinite (it is in fact linear w.r.t $t$). How do you intuitively understand how the integral (or infinite sum) of infinite variance quantities results in a quantity with finite variance?

Your question title is at odds with the question body.  Consider editing your question (body or title) for clarity.  The title is why the Wiener process is what it is (probably because Wiener, and others, found it useful).  The body is about the relationship between the variance of white noise vs. the variance of the output of a Wiener process (which is both interesting and answerable in a mathematical context).

Thank you! I have attempted to edit the title for clarity.

A sampled white noise has a finite variance, not infinite variance. A continuous white noise signal, which has infinite bandwidth, is a purely theoretical construction and will be limited in practice by the reality of finite bandwidth (so cannot be achieved). Ultimately any measurement system that can be used will have finite bandwidth, and so the more practical definition of white noise is noise that has a constant power spectral density within that bandwidth, and for that case a finite power can be defined.
The time domain integration from $0$ to $t$ of white noise is a random walk process, which has a variance that grows with $t$ (non-stationary), but if we scale that by $t$ (to be an average), the variance will be constant.
I attempt to provide an intuition as to why we can have a finite power white noise signal at this other StackExchange question:
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/87654/21048

Thank you, the book I was looking at defines autocorrelation at time delta $\tau$ as $G(\tau) = \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T} \xi(t)\xi(t + \tau)dt$ while also claiming the autocorrelation for white noise is $\delta(\tau)$. This led me to believe that white noise has infinite variance since by the book's definition, $G(0) = \mathbb{E}[\xi(t)^2]=\delta(0)=\infty$.
I believe the consistent definition of autocorrelation (so that the autocorrelation of white noise is $\delta(\tau)$) would be $G(\tau) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \xi(t)\xi(t + \tau)dt$, without normalizing by time.
