# Power spectral density convergence for finite samples

Tags: noise, power-spectral-density

Suppose a sequence $\{a_k\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ has power spectral density

$$
S_{\mathbf{a}}(f) := \lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{f_0 n}\left| \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2\pi f_0 a_k \exp(-2\pi ikf/f_0)   \right|^2 \right]
$$

where $f_0$ is the frequency of an "ideal" clock so that the rising edge of the clock occurs at $t_k = k/f_0 + a_k$.

Suppose we can only draw $m$ samples from the infinite sequence. How fast does the quantity

$$
S_{\mathbf{a}}^{(m)}(f) := \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{f_0 m}\left| \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} 2\pi f_0 a_k \exp(-2\pi ikf/f_0)   \right|^2 \right]
$$

converge to $S_{\mathbf{a}}(f)$? Can general statements be made? (If general statements cannot be made, I am content with results restricted to sequences that are roughly flicker.)

Comment: What kind of phase you speak of? As long as I understand, PSD does not preserve phase... maybe I missed something

Comment: I have changed to the terminology "power spectral density" rather than phase noise.

Comment: I would prefer if you might adopt a notational convention that is more common within the electrical engineering discipline.  What is the *"fundamental period"*, $T_0$?  Is it the sampling period?  Or the period of some periodic function that you haven't told us about?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Hopefully clarified.

Comment: $t_k = k/f_0 + a_k$ doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: This notation is standard; see "Understanding Jitter and Phase Noise" by Dalt, chapter 2.

Comment: No.  Within the electrical engineering discipline, the notation is not anywhere near standard.  $a_k$ appears to be a discrete function of "time" (we would call it "$x[n]$" but that's not the issue) and you're computing the DTFT and squaring it.   Your "$f_0$" appears to be the sampling frequency and "$k/f_0$" appears to be the continuous-time at the $k$th sample.  "$f/f_0$" appears to be normalized ordinary frequency in the DTFT and is less than $\frac12$. But I have seen ***nothing*** where you add the discrete function of time to the continuous-time value.  That expression makes zero sense.

Comment: Please refer to the referenced text. This is indeed standard. a_k is not a discrete function of time, is truly a sequence. f_0 is the frequency of the base clock.

Answer (score 1):

I am restating the question using standard EE DSP notation as we might find in O&S (and correcting errors regarding spurious appearance of $2 \pi$):

---

Suppose a discrete-time, [finite power signal](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16821/how-to-check-if-a-signal-is-power-signal-or-energy-signal/16822#16822)

$$x[n] \triangleq x(n/f_\mathrm{s}) \qquad \qquad \text{(where } x(t) \text{ is the continuous-time signal being sampled)}$$

has power spectral density

$$
S_{x}(f) = \lim_{N\to \infty}\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{N}\left| \sum\limits_{n=-N/2}^{N/2-1} x[n] e^{-j 2 \pi n f/f_\mathrm{s}}   \right|^2 \right]
$$

where $f_\mathrm{s}$ is the frequency of an "ideal" clock *(the sample rate)* so that the rising edge of the clock occurs at $t_n = n/f_\mathrm{s} + x[n]$ ***(...this expression makes no sense)***.

Suppose we can only draw $M$ samples from the infinite sequence. How fast does the quantity

$$
S_{x}^{(M)}(f) = \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{M}\left| \sum\limits_{n=-M/2}^{M/2-1} x[n] e^{-j 2 \pi n f/f_\mathrm{s}}   \right|^2 \right]
$$

converge to $S_{x}(f)$? Can general statements be made? (If general statements cannot be made, I am content with results restricted to sequences that are roughly flicker.)

---

The next thing that the OP should realize is the standard definition of the Discrete-Time Fourier Transform (DTFT):

$$ X\big(e^{j\omega}\big) \triangleq \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x[n] e^{-j \omega n} $$

Which defines the normalized angular frequency $\omega$ in terms of continuous-time frequency $f$ as

$$ \omega \triangleq 2 \pi \frac{f}{f_\mathrm{s}} $$

***THAT*** is "standard notation" in the DSP subdiscipline within the electrical engineering discipline.

Comment: +1 for formalizing notation.

Comment: x[n] is not a sampling of a continuous time function. It is truly a sequence in the mathematical sense.

Comment: $x[n]$ is another notation for $x_n$.  It's a sequence of numbers.  Now ***if*** your sequence of numbers represent something at a precise time $t_n=\frac{n}{f_\mathrm{s}}$ that's sampled continuous-time signal. Then your normalized angular frequency is related to frequency in the continuous -time domain (Hz) as $$ \omega = 2 \pi \frac{f}{f_\mathrm{s}}$$ You need no other reason to have the sample rate $f_\mathrm{s}$ in the equations.